# Exchange 2003 Internet Mail Size Limits

Tags: exchange-2003

I have unsuccessfully tried to increase per user incoming mail size settings by editing their user account settings on our Exchange server, but large incoming mail from external domains is still blocked using the default global settings.

After reading here: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;322679

I see that

> All Internet e-mail messages use the global setting for limits on sending and on receiving. The message categorizer evaluates the sender's sending limit and the recipient's receiving limit. In example 2 earlier, a user with a user mailbox limit of 3 MB could receive messages from another user with a 3-MB sending limit. Because Internet users use the global setting, they can send only a 2-MB message.

Which to me is madness! Surely if I want to allow a user to receive mail up to a certain size then I should be able to set it as such?

Is there a specific way of getting round this? Would setting the global defaults high and setting a lower, say 10MB, limit on the SMTP connector do the trick?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems convoluted, but because a user may be scoped to a any one of a number of servers, therefore to any number of Routing Group connectors and/or SMTP Virtual Servers and/or Mailbox Stores, you'll have to think of it in this manner:

What's the maximum size you want to allow users to send/recieve regardless of Routing Group or SMTP Virtual Server or Mailbox Store? Set this limit in the Global settings.

All other size limits are applicable to the particular Routing Group connector, SMTP Virtual Server, and Mailbox Store.

It sounds like you have a single server installation, which in my opinion makes the concept a little confusing. It's easier to understand how the size limits come in to play when you have multiple servers, routing groups, etc.

My advice would be to determine what the maximum size you want to allow is and set that at the Global settings, the Routing Group connector, the SMTP Virtual Server, and the Mailbox Store.

Comment: One server, yes. I see where you are coming from with the global setting. I guess the max I want for any user would be 50MB. So I will set that in my global settings. But I dont want ALL users to have this allowance. So if I set 10MB on the SMTP virtual server (since all users go through this) then when I set individual user account limits the mail will now be allowed through since the global settings are higher and the user settings take precedence over the SMTP virtual server settings?